# how to write to a class which extends User with ModelForm

Tags: django, sqlite, django-forms

I have a class which extends `User` so that I can also store physical address.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=80, default="")
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, default=None)
    post_number = models.IntegerField(default=None)
```

The model in sqlite database holds columns:

```
frontend_customuser:
    id
    street
    user_id # not sure how this is created, concat of CustomUser and User fields?
    post_name
    post_number
```

I have a form which enables the user to modify data from `User` and `CustomUser` like so:

```
class BasicUserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']


class CustomUserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['street', 'post_name', 'post_number']
```

In `views.py` I'm trying to display/write to DB as seen below. I am able to display and modify the `User` table, but can't touch the (as of yet empty) table governed by `CustomUser` (error I get is `NOT NULL constraint failed: frontend_customuser.user_id`). Any tips on what I might be doing wrong? Is there a more straightforward way of writing all this data through `CustomUser` (since it extends `User`) only?

```
def settings(request):
    # Prepare data to be filled into forms. User should always exist so no try/except call.
    prefill_user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)

    # In case CustomUser table is empty, instantiate a CustomUser with request.user.id user_id.
    try:
        prefill_customuser = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        prefill_customuser = CustomUser(user_id=request.user.id)

    if request.method == "GET":
        # If CustomUser table is empty, fields will appear empty. If prefill_customuser is successful
        # at retrieving data, I expect this to be populated by values from the database.
        settings_form_user = BasicUserSettingsForm(initial={'first_name': prefill_user.first_name,
                                                            'last_name': prefill_user.last_name,
                                                            'email': prefill_user.email},
                                                   instance=prefill_user)
        settings_form_customuser = CustomUserSettingsForm(initial={'street': prefill_customuser.street,
                                                                   'post_name': prefill_customuser.post_name,
                                                                   'post_number': prefill_customuser.post_number},
                                                          instance=prefill_customuser)

    if request.method == "POST":
        settings_form_user = BasicUserSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=prefill_user)
        try:
            customuser_instance = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
            settings_form_customuser = CustomUserSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=customuser_instance)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            settings_form_customuser = CustomUserSettingsForm(request.POST)

        if settings_form_user.is_valid() and settings_form_customuser.is_valid():
            settings_form_user.save()
            settings_form_customuser.save()
        else:
            settings_form_user = BasicUserSettingsForm(request.POST)
            settings_form_customuser = CustomUserSettingsForm(request.POST)

    return render(request, 'frontend/nastavitve.html',
                  {'settings_form_user': settings_form_user, 'settings_form_customuser': settings_form_customuser})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought extending the `User` class will be the most elegant solution, however I may not be doing something right. For now, I've opted for a separate table which has a `ForeignKey` linked to `User` table. The implementation as described below now takes values entered into the form, records/updates the table in database and serves up-to-date data in forms.

```
# --models.py
class UserAddress(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=80, default="")
    # post = models.ForeignKey(PostNameNum, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, default=None)
    post_number = models.IntegerField(default=None)

# --forms.py
class BasicUserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

class UserAddressSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        fields = ['street', 'post_name', 'post_number']

# --views.py
def settings(request):
    # Prepare data to be filled into forms. User should always exist so no try/except call.
    prefill_user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)

    # In case CustomUser table is empty, instantiate a CustomUser with request.user.id user_id.
    try:
        prefill_customuser = UserAddress.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        prefill_customuser = UserAddress(id=User(id=request.user.id))

    if request.method == "GET":
        settings_form_user = BasicUserSettingsForm(initial={'first_name': prefill_user.first_name,
                                                            'last_name': prefill_user.last_name,
                                                            'email': prefill_user.email},
                                                   instance=prefill_user)
        settings_form_customuser = UserAddressSettingsForm(initial={'street': prefill_customuser.street,
                                                                    'post_name': prefill_customuser.post_name,
                                                                    'post_number': prefill_customuser.post_number},
                                                           instance=prefill_customuser)

    if request.method == "POST":
        settings_form_user = BasicUserSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=prefill_user)
        try:
            settings_form_customuser = UserAddressSettingsForm(request.POST, instance=prefill_customuser)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            settings_form_customuser = UserAddressSettingsForm(request.POST)

        # if settings_form_user.is_valid() and settings_form_customuser.is_valid():
        if settings_form_customuser.is_valid():
            settings_form_user.save()
            settings_form_customuser.save()
        else:
            settings_form_user = BasicUserSettingsForm(request.POST)
            settings_form_customuser = UserAddressSettingsForm(request.POST)

    return render(request, 'frontend/nastavitve.html',
                  {'settings_form_user': settings_form_user,
                   'settings_form_customuser': settings_form_customuser}
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It is old way creating custom user with `OneToOne` field to basic Django `User` model. In your case you need to extend `AbstractUser`, it is available since Django 1.8:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=80, default="")
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, default=None)
```

and put new user in `settings.py`:
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = <app_name>.CustomUser`
This approach works if you want add aditional fields for base user model. If you want override it more complex, you need to exted `AbstractBaseUser`

Comment: After tinkering around a bit I got an error when trying to authenticate with google saying there's no `password` field. Have I overwritten something or is this expected? I don't see any of this in the documentation, unfortunately. Is it safe to go about implementing "User" anew?